# Create matrix using information from .txt file python

Tags: python, matrix, python-2.7

I have a .txt file that reads:

dog  bird  32.0
raccoon   dog   43
bird   raccoon 16

I want to make a matrix in python that has columns dog, bird, raccoon, and rows dog, bird, raccoon and inserts the number in the matrix cell.

for example have 32.0 in the cross section of dog and bird.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to write code if your text file was formatted a little differently. Kind of like an x column, a y column, and a z column. Something that looks like this:

```
Dog      Bird     32
Raccoon  Dog      43
Bird     Raccoon  16
```

I did this to make it work. It's not quite right, but it may get you on the right track.

```
def printMatrix(matrix,rows,columns,row):
    print matrix[row-1][columns-1]

if __name__=='__main__':
    matrix=[]

    with open('matrix.txt','r') as f:

        for l in f:
            t=l.split(',')
            matrix.append(t)
    printMatrix(matrix, 3, 3, 1)
```